# python foreign character in csv

Tags: python, encode

I have a little csv which contains foreign characters, like Chinese.
How can I display them in Chinese instead of those \xa5\\xa4\ string???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the [docs for the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)? It includes examples of how to wrap `csv` to handle Unicode data.